# Leaflet-dvf ReactJS implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am upgrading code base to React and can't understand why leaflet and leaflet-dvf is not working - no `ChoroplethDataLayer` is displayed.

So actual component code is as follows:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react' // v15.6.1
import { render, findDOMNode} from 'react-dom' // v15.6.1
import 'leaflet' // v1.2.0
// leaflet.css is added in HTML, because of problems with webpack and *.png paths

import 'leaflet-dvf' // v0.3.1
import 'leaflet-dvf/dist/css/dvf.css' // v0.3.1
import './countryData.js'
import { provider } from 'leaflet-providers' //v1.1.17

class Map extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.drawMap()
    }

    drawMap() {
        // Initialize map on component rendered <div>
        let map = L.map(findDOMNode(this)).setView([this.props.lat, this.props.lng], this.props.zoom);

        // Show legend box
        let legendControl = new L.Control.Legend();
        legendControl.addTo(map);

        // Add the Stamen toner tiles as a base layer
        let tileLayer = L.tileLayer.provider('Stamen.TonerLite', {
            minZoom: 2,
            zIndex: 1
        })
        tileLayer.addTo(map);


        // Options and data are calculated (the same as in old code base - working)
        let options = this.props.options;
        let data = this.props.datum;

        // Show Chropleth map in overlayPane
        var baseLayer = new L.ChoroplethDataLayer(data, options);
        baseLayer.addTo(map);

    }

    render() {
        const mapStyle = {
            height: this.props.height, // 500px
            width: this.props.width, // 500px
        }

        return (
            <div style={mapStyle}></div>
        )
    }
}
```

You can see in following picture: [image: First]

that `Legend` is shown correctly, but no `Choropleth` layer is shown, however it is generated and you can see it in this picture `leaflet-overlay-pane`

[image: Second]

If I delete from DOM divs with class `leflet-shadow-pane`, `leaflet-tile-pane` and remove `leaflet-pane` class from `leaflet-overtlay-pane`, as you can se in following picture:

[image]

then I can see that `Choropleth` layer is generated and visible as in this example:

[image]

So I have following questions:

1) How to make `Choropleth` visible and in right size? (baseLayer.bringToFront() and zIndex didn't help)

2) How to correctly import `leaflet` and `leaflet-dvf` packages (they both are in "L" namespace)? (At now I am doing `import "leaflet"` and `import "leaflet-dvf"`)

3) How to correctly structure and import `contryData.js` which are used to lookup and render countries/cities/etc. This file is located at [github in leaflet-dvf/src/data](https://github.com/humangeo/leaflet-dvf/blob/master/src/data/countryData.js) ? (At now I copied this file and at the top added `import "leaflet"`). What are best practices for this in ES6/React?

4) Is it possible to use `react-leaflet` with `leaflet-dvf` and provide full example of that?

Comment: are you using the correct version of leafet? leaflet-dvf is not up to date project, I don't think it works with leaflet v1

Comment: @AlexParij - good catch on this. I tried versions `leaflet` from 7.7 till 1.20 and all `leaflet-dvf` versions. In React this didn't made any effect, but in plain JavaScript/jQuery solutions works well. One more comment on this is comment in [leafet-dvf github](https://github.com/humangeo/leaflet-dvf/issues/119) that 1.0dev branch is compatible with leaflet 1.X versions.